# I'm misunderstanding Haskell's Control.Parallel and would like clarification

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm trying to figure out Haskell's Control.Parallel module, and I wrote the following (tMap is a base case for time comparisons):

```
import Control.Parallel

paraMap, tMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

paraMap _ [] = []
paraMap f [x] = [f x]
paraMap f (x : xs@(y : ys)) = (f y `par` f x) : paraMap f xs

tMap _ [] = []
tMap f (x : xs) = f x : tMap f xs
```

The idea being that paraMap will begin computing the next element before it's finished with the current one. My tests show that it's performing worse then tMap though. I'm guessing this is because par introduces more overhead, and because I'm not using it correctly, it isn't producing enough gains to overcome the costs.

What's wrong with my above example? As I understand it, `x 'par' y` basically means "I need `x` later, so compute it in parallel, but return `y` for now" (similar to how seq works, but embodied in a spark, which allows for the chance that it will be computed on a separate thread).

The only thing I can think of, is it's being confused because I need the next element in a separate instance of the function (the recurse). I suppose I could make `paraMap` a wrapper around the actual recursion, and explicitly pass the next `par`'d element to the next recurse; but that seems clumsy.

I tried debugging it by compiling it with `:! ghc -o -threaded <fileName> "<fileName><fileExt>" +RTS -s` (formatted as a tool in GHCi) with the following as my main:

```
main = print $ paraMap (\x -> foldl (+) 0 [1..x * 100]) [1..500]
```

and received the following feedback:

```
75,657,304 bytes allocated in the heap
      32,738,472 bytes copied during GC
       8,926,880 bytes maximum residency (7 sample(s))
         139,208 bytes maximum slop
              19 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0        82 colls,     0 par    0.02s    0.04s     0.0005s    0.0199s
  Gen  1         7 colls,     0 par    0.08s    0.12s     0.0168s    0.0587s

  TASKS: 5 (1 bound, 4 peak workers (4 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.15s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.05s  (  0.30s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.09s  (  0.16s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.02s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.16s  (  0.62s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,614,022,485 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  40.0% of total user, 10.1% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

Unless I'm reading it wrong, no sparks were spawned, which is definitely an issue.

Am I thinking about this completely wrong? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe there is a runtime flag you need to pass the executable, too, something like "+RTS N4" for running on 4 CPUs.

Comment: Your hunch ("the only thing I can think of") is correct.  Clumsiness, as always, can be mitigated with intelligent use of abstraction, but try it the clumsy way first.

Comment: `foldl (+) 0`, _really_? Then you might as well write `sum`. Surely you mean `foldl' (+) 0`.

Comment: @Leftaroundabout It was late, and I was just messing around. I forgot about the space leak of lazy foldl. Fairly irrelevant though as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Kris I think I can pass that to GHC too. I tried it, and it didn't complain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `par` causes `f y` to be sparked, but its result is never used (it's not bound to anything so you have no access to it):

```
paraMap f (x : xs@(y : ys)) = (f y `par` f x) : paraMap f xs
```

The next application of `f` on `y` (which will happen as `f x` in the recursive call to `paraMap`) knows nothing of this sparked `f y` computation, since you never passed it to it.

An even simpler example, suffering from the same problem, would be something like

```
foo x y = bar x `par` bar y `pseq` bar x + bar y
```

Again, the second calls to `bar` have no access to the results of the already-sparked computations. Instead, you should write

```
foo x y = let x' = bar x
              y' = bar y
          in x' `par` y' `pseq` x' + y'
```

Comment: I would have thought in your example that it would be able to tell that the `bar x`s are the same. Oh well, thank you.

Comment: To be 100% honest, some CSE optimization pass could make my 'wrong' example work in that case.

Comment: It still doesn't work, despite using binds. I decided to try an even simpler case, which just takes 2 functions (one a sum, the other a sum that first doubles each element, bound as `s` and `ds` respectively), and adds them like so `sumsP xs = s `par` (ds `pseq` (s + ds))`. It still runs slower then it's non-parallelized counterpart, and the log shows that 0 sparks were created. In the above case, do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Whoops. The infix backticks made that format weird.

Comment: Do be aware that `par` and `pseq` only evaluate to WHNF. You might want to look at `Control.Parallel.Strategies` if you want deeper evaluation; check out chapter 5 of http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/par-tutorial-cadarache.pdf

Comment: So if I `force` or `deepseq` the values, it should work? I'm just concerned that sparks don't seem to be forming at all. If I print a log (like in the question), it says `...SPARKS: 0...`, which seems to mean that they aren't being created in the first place. Most of the tutorials I've seen mention that sparks being GC'd, or fizzled is a common pitfall, but none mention them not being created in the first place. Is the values not being evaluated fully able to cause this? And doesn't `pseq` cause full evaluation? I thought that it was basically `seq`, just with a defined order.

Comment: I tried using `fpseq` (`fpseq a = pseq (force a)`) in place of `pseq`, but it didn't change anything.